# How I can block all pages except loginpage?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I want to block all pages except the login and error page with Spring Security, but if I do `pattern="/*"` it will lock absolutely all pages and result in an endless redirect. How I can lock all pages except login and error page for authorization?

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/"  access="ROLE_USER"/>
    <form-login
        login-page="/login"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout"/>
    <csrf/>
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="root" password="root" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can intercept login and error page first with access ANONYMOUSLY then intercept all pages, interception ordered based on order you write it, like

```
<http>
<intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
<form-login login-page='/login.jsp'/>
</http>
```

in spring security documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-form-and-basic)